# Buttons Which Change Color, Each Time Pressed

Tags: dynamic, color, button

I need to have 100 buttons, which their color is defined by the parity of number of times they are pressed: If they're pressed an even number of times their color is blue, and otherwise red. I don't know how to use 'Button' and 'Dynamic' to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Example right from the help `DynamicModule[{x = 0}, 
 Button["xxx", x = Mod[x + 1/10, 1], Background -> Dynamic[Hue[x]]]]` Voting to close

Comment: To add to what belisarius said, you just need to change the `x = Mod[...]` line to return `Blue` if `x` is `Red` and vice versa. That automatically takes care of the even/odd. Also, remove the `Hue[]`.

Comment: @belisarius As a matter of fact, I had found another example from the help before my post, but I couldn't change it so that the red/blue colors work.

Comment: I don't remember where but there is nice way shown in documentation with `ReplaceAll`: `DynamicModule[{bg = Red}, 
 Button["xxx", bg = bg /. {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Red}, 
  Background -> Dynamic[bg]]]`

Comment: @Behzad The colors problem is easy (you got three comments about that instantly) the hard part is doing that for 100 buttons. But you're not still facing it

Answer (score 5):

Done!

```
Table[DynamicModule[{x = 0}, 
   Button[i + 10 j, x = Mod[x + .5, 1], 
    Background -> Dynamic[Hue[x]]]], {j, 0, 9}, {i, 1, 10}] // Grid
```

Comment: That's the way. Well done  :)

Comment: @belisarius I was editing that:(

Comment: afarin behzad!!!